# I want to use Alexa API to read grocery list (for display in a web app.) Must I write a "skill"?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

First my apologies if this is a dumb question, or has been asked before.  I've been searching for a couple of days and can't find an answer.  This usually means I'm asking a dumb question. ;-)

I have a rPi and touchscreen in my kitchen; it displays helpful things like appointments for next 7 days, weather next 7 days, news headlines, etc.  It's a web app I wrote in Angular 7, and it queries a NodeJS v8 backend which I also wrote.  This was a hobby project to learn Angular and Node.

The Node app performs all interactions with the outside world, using Google's Calendar API to get appointments, Yahoo Weather API, newsapi.org.  All of these integrations followed the same pattern -- obtain some apikey token, and use that when invoking some API method to get the requested data in a JSON wad.

Now, I would like to also get the grocery list from my Echo.  After reviewing Amazon's Alexa API documentation, it doesn't appear that I can do this the same way as the previous three integrations I did.  Must I really write a "skill" for this, though I never intend to invoke it on the Echo?

And if so, could you point to a decent sample?  None of the samples provided by Amazon utilize the Lists API.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must create a skill in order to receive `access_token`. And then - [Out of Session Interaction](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/access-the-alexa-shopping-and-to-do-lists.html#out-of-session-interaction) feature might be useful.